# How can I center items horizontally inside uistackview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I have a UIScrollView and an UIStackView. I want to add elements from top to bottom and let the scrollview scroll only vertically. I have trouble with this and don't really get what the problem is.

So I added the constrains that the UIScrollView should stick to the super view on all sides, added the stackview, you can see its constrain on the pic, also added a label with fixed width. I want this label to be center in the scrollview without the scrollview starting to scroll horizontally.

I think Im missing some constrains? The scroll view also says it has "ambiguous scrollable content width".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to fix ambiguous you should create a contentView for the scrollView as Apple recommends and give it width of outmost view then put the stackView inside it and Change alignment of the stackview to `.center` + alignment of the label itself

```
       Scrollview  // pinned to top , leading , trailing ,bottom
          contentView // pinned to top , leading , trailing ,bottom , and have width = outmost view (very important)
             stackView
```

Comment: What does this mean "give it width of outmost view"? I want everything to stretch the current screen width except the stackview or the label.

Comment: anyway the contentView inside the scrollView must have a static width or give it width of outmostView (Outer view) in document outline that is self.view in code

Comment: Thanks I think I got it